# Zend auth and redirection in Controller plugin

Tags: zend-framework

I have simple front controller plugin which contains this code:
http://pastebin.com/m155c59b0

When session expire if user is on /admin/controller_name it will be redirected to auth module but if user is on /admin/controller_name/action_name it wouldn't be redirected, he will get error from error controller with message that action doesn't exist.
Anybody know what's the problem and how to fix it!?

Comment: Could you please post the code? The pastebin link has expired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the action name as well (using `->setActionName()`). Otherwise the original request's action remains unchanged and the request ends up being redirected to `/auth/index/original_action_name`, which presumably doesn't exist and causes the error.

Comment: Tnx, a lot this is logical solution but I wasn't able to figure this out without your help